# How do I sum up all the digits in a number which is given as a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a number as a string. For example:

```
str_num = "12345"
```

So,

```
str_num[0] = 1
str_num[1] = 2
str_num[2] = 3
str_num[3] = 4
str_num[4] = 5
```

But

```
str_num[0] + str_num[1] + str_num[2] + str_num[3] + str_num[4] = 255
```

I want the result to be the sum of all the digits in the string. In this case that is:

```
str_num[0] + str_num[1] + str_num[2] + str_num[3] + str_num[4] = 15
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str_num[0] - '0' + str_num[1] - '0' + ...
```

is one way, i.e. subtract 5 lots of `'0'` from your current total. The subtraction of `'0'` is idiomatic in C and C++ as both standards insist that any encoding of digits has them in consecutive order and in a contiguous block.

Comment: Understood. Thanks :-)

Comment: But *don't* apply the idiom for alpha characters though, it's not strictly portable.

Comment: I have 0 knowledge about alpha characters. Where I can educate myself about that?

Comment: I'd read Kernighan and Ritchie "The C programming language". Yes it's old, but it's short and brilliantly written.

Comment: Okay man! Thanks for the help.